# Reciprocal ping: "Request timed out" and "Destination host unreachable"

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ping

I use a VPN to connect to the internal network of my university. There is an Ubuntu machine in the university that is used for computational purposes. When I connect to the VPN I can ping every machine except the desired machine.

By pining the target machine from my computer I get:

```
Request timed out.
```

By pinging my own machine from the target machine I get:

```
Destination host unreachable
```

I can ping every other machine from my machine, and my machine from every other machine without a problem.

May someone please help me in this issue?

Comment: Is ping enabled on the target  machine? I could see the target machine having ping disabled, which is a separate issue from the target being unable to reach your machine (your machine is behind firewall or NAT). Can you `ssh` into the target machine?

Answer (score 0):

Your question requires an answer for two network scenarios.  You are getting Request Timed Out when pinging the Ubuntu machine from your computer.

You get Destination Host Unreachable message when you ping your machine from the Ubuntu machine. First, let me explain why you are getting these messages.

1. The ICMP error message Request Timed Out explains your computer waited for replies from the destination host for a reasonable
   amount of time but received none.

   Ref:  https://www.corenetworkz.com/2009/05/request-timed-out.html
2. The Destination Host Unreachable error tells that the ping packets from your computer cannot find a route to the destination IP
   address(destination host).

   Ref: https://www.systosys.com/2020/01/fix-destination-host-unreachable.html

**How to Fix this problem**

- The first step I ask you is whether you can ping the Ubuntu machine from your computer without a VPN.  It is to check whether this problem is due to the VPN.
- If it is not a VPN-related problem, my first suspect is the Firewall. Disable the firewall and ping the remote machine again.
- My third assumption is the faulty routing table. You need to flush the routing table cache and try to ping again.
- If nothing works, I suggest you run the TraceRoute command.

  Try  *tracert [Destination Machine IP Address]*

Show the screenshot to us. I hope by analyzing the TraceRoute, we can identify the exact reason.